# Upgrade popup says my graphic hardware is not supported. Is this true?

Tags: graphics, hardware

I have an hp pavilion dv7 with a Radeon HD4200 graphic card. When I try to upgrade i get this message -Your graphics hardware may not be fully supported in Ubuntu 12.10.

Running the 'unity' desktop environment is not fully supported by your graphics hardware. You will maybe end up in a very slow environment after the upgrade. Our advice is to keep the LTS version for now. For more information see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Bugs/UpdateManagerWarningForUnity3D Do you still want to continue with the upgrade?

Should I continue or not?

Answer (score 3):

Well for sure there is no FGLRX driver for your card. Moreover, I have radeon hd4550 and i've noticed performance drop using open source driver. Nothing nightmarish but i was used to more responsive system. So I would advise against an upgrade, at least for some time.

If you are willing to do some experimentation then you can try to downgrade xserver in ubuntu 12.10, so it will support the current FGLRX legacy driver. You can find full instruction [here](http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2012/10/how-to-install-amd-catalyst-legacy.html). Be advised that it can create all kinds of problems.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons people use Linux is that they could use old hardware, and not be forced to spend all kinds of money on upgrades to simply feed a bloated OS.

Apparently, Ubuntu have taken a page from Microsoft with this release, forcing hardware obsolescence, limiting choices, and yet again putting out a major release which breaks the network drivers (for about the fourth time).

Perhaps it's time to slow down the release cycle, get this right first, and move away from the current user-beta releases that many of us ditched Microsoft for in the first place, and regain the confidence of the user community...

Comment: You've got to remember that Ubuntu __is__ open governed - hardware obsolescence is a side-effect of a decision that the community made which enhanced the OS in some way. It's not like Mark Shuttleworth sits in a big leather chair and every six months picks a user base to not support any more.

In terms of releases which break things accidentally - well that's something that comes about as a result of not having enough testing. That's something the community could also get more involved with.